# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input and in the network tab the preview is set to empty

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, fetch-api

I am currently working on an asset management system. I am in the part of search of a good by means of its code. Now, when I paint the result of this search I get the following results

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

So I go to the network tab where my sql query is and surprise surprise it appears blank (empty), and that's where I was also in the same thing since that had never happened to me. Thanks for reading me.

[image]

PHP

```
<?php 
$value=$_POST['valor'];
$op=$_POST['opcion'];

 if ($op==='B') {
include '../modelo/conexiondb.php';

    try{
        $sql=$conexion->prepare('SELECT fecha, nombre as clasificacion, tipo_de_bien, concepto, cantidad, n_bien, n_control, nombre_y_descripcion, departamentos as departamento, v_unitario, estado as estatus from bienes INNER JOIN clasificacion on bienes.clasificacion=clasificacion.id_d INNER JOIN concepto_mov_incorporados on bienes.concep_mov=concepto_mov_incorporados.codigo INNER JOIN departamentos on bienes.departamento=departamentos.id_depa INNER JOIN estatus on bienes.estatus=estatus.id where n_bien=?');
        $sql->bind_param('s', $value);
        $sql->execute();
        
        $respuesta = $sql->get_result()->fetch_all();

        $sql->close();
        
        $conexion->close();
    }catch(Exception $e){
    //En caso de un error, tomar la excepcion
    $respuesta = array('respuesta' =>$e->getMessage() );
     }
     echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
  ?>
```

JS

```
const d=document;
d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
detectarOpcion();
 });
function detectarOpcion () {
 let $input=d.getElementById('valor'),
 $boton=d.getElementById('btn-buscar');
 $boton.addEventListener('click', e=>{
 let $select=d.getElementById('select').value;
            const datos=new FormData();
            datos.append('valor', $input.value);
            datos.append('opcion', $select) 
        fetch('./modelo/nbien_busqueda_y_ncontrol.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos,
        })
    .then(res=>{return res.ok ?(res.json()) :Promise.reject(res);})
    .then(data=>{ console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        let respuesta='';
        for(let i in data ){
            respuesta += `<tr>
                <td>${data[i].fecha}</td>
                <td>${data[i].clasificacion}</td>
                <td>${data[i].tipo_de_bien}</td>
                <td>${data[i].concepto}</td>
                <td>${data[i].cantidad}</td>
                <td>${data[i].n_bien}</td>
                <td>${data[i].n_control}</td>
                <td>${data[i].nombre_y_descripcion}</td>
                <td>${data[i].departamento}</td>
                <td>${data[i].v_unitario}</td>
                <td>${data[i].estatus}</td>
             
            </tr>`
            
        }
        d.querySelector('.contenedor-datatables').classList.remove('none');
        d.querySelector('.tbody').innerHTML=respuesta;
        

    
    })
    .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err); 
})
.finally(()=>{
    console.log('Esto se ejecutará independientemente del resultado de la Promesa Fetch')
})

})

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bienes-busqueda').DataTable();
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with:
`for(let i in data )`
You should use something like following in this case:
`for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1)`
Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope still doesn't show me the logs